# Partial derivative of a vector-valued function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a homogeneous demand function of degree 0: $x(\alpha p,\alpha w)=x(p,w)$, where $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_L)$ is a vector and $w$ is a scalar.

Differentiate $x(\alpha p,\alpha w)=x(p,w)$ with respect to $\alpha$.

And here I don't know how to differentiate.
If we write  $x(\alpha p,\alpha w)=x(p,w)$ as  $x(u,v)=x(p,w)$ then using the chain rule we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^L \frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial u_i}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \alpha}=0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^L \frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial u_i}p_i+\frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial v}w=0$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^L \frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial u_i}p_i+\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial v}w=0$$

But the answer is $$\sum_{i=1}^L \frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial p_i}p_i+\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial w}w=0$$

The question is how $\partial u_i$ is substituted with $\partial p_i$ and $\partial v$ is substituted with $\partial w$

Comment: I think they're supposed to mean the same thing. This is an ambiguity in the derivative notation. What is the meaning of $$\frac{df(2x)}{dx}$$ for example? Does it mean to differentiate $f$, and then evaluate it at $2x$ (thus giving $f'(2x)$)? Or does it mean to evaluate $f$ at $2x$, and then differentiate it (by the chain rule, thus giving $f'(2x)\cdot2$)? We see that the prime notation $f'$ avoids such ambiguity. It generalizes to several variables: use $f^{(1,0)}$ and $f^{(0,1)}$ instead of $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$.

Comment: @mr_e_man , I think that $\frac{df(2x)}{dx}$ is $2f^{\prime}(2x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess for each $i\in\{1,\dots, L\}$ we have
$$\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial p_i}=\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial (\alpha p_i)}\cdot \frac{d(\alpha p_i)}{d p_i}=\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial u_i}\cdot \alpha.$$
Similarly we have
$$\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial (\alpha w)}\cdot \frac{d(\alpha w)}{d w}=\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial v}\cdot \alpha.$$

Then your answer differs from the answer by the factor $\frac 1\alpha$.

For instance, let $L=1$,$x(p_1,w)=\frac {p_1}w$ and $w,\alpha\ne 0$. Then $u_1=\alpha p_1$ and $v=\alpha w$. So

$$\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial p_1}=\frac{\partial\frac{p_1}{w}}{\partial p_1}=\frac 1w\mbox{ and }\frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial u_1}=\frac{\partial\frac{u_1}{v}}{\partial u_1}=\frac 1v=\frac 1{\alpha w}.$$

Similarly we have

$$\frac{\partial x(\alpha p,\alpha w)}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial\frac{p_1}{w}}{\partial w}=-\frac {p_1}{w^2}\mbox{ and }\frac{\partial x(u,v)}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial\frac{u_1}{v}}{\partial v}=-\frac {u_1}{v^2}=-\frac {\alpha p_1}{(\alpha w)^2}.$$